# The diode of the lowest voltage

Tags: electronics

Which diode (semiconductor material) has the lowest voltage in the direction of conductivity?

Comment: I do not know of a diode with "a" voltage. Please specify what voltage You mean.

Comment: Maybe he means band gap? This question definitely needs clarification.

Comment: I agree with @Colin, this needs to be clarified. When it is, I'll be happy to reopen it (although it may turn out that it's off topic here, in which case we might be able to migrate it to E&R.SE).

Comment: Schottky, down to 0.1V

Comment: Perhaps it should be rephrased as "Which diode (semicondutor material) has the lowest *forward* voltage drop." Then indeed, Schottky is the answer, but I'd like to see a longer explanation having to do with physics.

Comment: I have been confused and inarticulate at times. I am especially grateful to those with the patience to interpret my poor communication and correct my faulty assumptions. I think all the comments here are constructive, both the ones asking for clarification, and the ones suggesting rephrasing.

Comment: Hm, the comment that I was responding to is now deleted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact, Schottky Diodes

have the lowest **forward voltages**. This means, that this is not a question of band gap 
"voltage" (this is a energy difference originally!) but of technology. 
Second are Germanium point contact diodes with gold wires.

"Diodes" made from Galena maybe are very low too, but due to the wiggely properties 
I would not dare to write about the "impressions" I had some times for some seconds on a scope.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT
 Georg's note make me see that is not an answer to the OP.
     I leave the rest of the text only to make notice of a very promising new techonoly.
end EDIT

**[Superconducting Niobium Chip Smashes Silicon Power Consumption Standards](http://www.technologyreview.com/blog/arxiv/26560/?ref=rss)**
A superconducting logic chip with a clock speed of 6 GHz ***beats silicon energy efficiency by two orders of magnitude***

Ref: [Ultra-Low-Power Superconductor Logic](http://arxiv.org/abs/1103.4269)
Abstract:

> We have developed a new
>   superconducting digital technology,
>   Reciprocal Quantum Logic, that uses AC
>   power carried on a transmission line,
>   which also serves as a clock. Using
>   simple experiments we have
>   demonstrated zero static power
>   dissipation, thermally limited dynamic
>   power dissipation, high clock
>   stability, high operating margins and
>   low BER. These features indicate that
>   the technology is scalable to far more
>   complex circuits at a significant
>   level of integration. On the system
>   level, Reciprocal Quantum Logic
>   combines the high speed and low-power
>   signal levels of Single-Flux- Quantum
>   signals with the design methodology of
>   CMOS, including low static power
>   dissipation, low latency combinational
>   logic, and efficient device count.

Comment: I cannot see that diodes are used in that niobium technology. This is interesting, since superconducting logic was proposed several times since the 50ties, but where is the relation to forward voltages of diodes?

Comment: @Georg you said it very well. I did not read the paper and presumed that it has to be based in normal gates based on transistors to achieve digital treatment, and less power usually means less voltage. Now, that I looked inside, I find emerging technology even more interesting.

Comment: Strange, I thought that superconducting logic should exclude normal semiconductor logic. I was very curious by Your answer  until I saw what is behind. The priciple is the same as I know from 50ties. Called "Kryotron" then, afair

Comment: Here is the history: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryotron

Comment: It's OK, and thanks for link Cryotron. Semiconduction has nothing to do with superconducting. The Cryotron behaves as a transistor controlled by the current rather than voltage. The formulation of the abs "the design methodology of CMOS" plus "+ digital chip ...
Is this the rest of the story? [Josephson_effect] (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Josephson_effect) and [single electron transistor (superconducting and voltage controlled)] (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-electron_transistor). Superconductor digital is very promising.